# Can't trigger transition by toggling classes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make a simple transition but struggle doing it with jQuery.
I create the element that is to be transformed in JS in an eventListener like so:

```
const searchHint = `
  <h3 id="search_hint" class="invizible">
    Enter a search term to continue!
  </h3>
`
$('#search_label').append(searchHint)
$('#search_hint').removeClass('invizible').addClass('make_vizible')
```

In my stylesheet I've got those styles for the classes 'invizible' and 'make_vizible':

```
#search_hint.invizible {
  color: white;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}

#search_hint.make_vizible {
  color: #404040;
}
```

As I understand, this should result in the search hint element slowly fading in. I create it with the invizible class, where a transition attribute is present and also a start value for the attribute to be transformed. Then I switch the classes, to a class with a different color value.

What happens, is that the element is just displayed, not animated.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to wrap the changing of the classes in a timeout for the browser to have time to do a repaint etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. The `transition` property is set in `invizible` class. So once you remove it, that property is not applicable. To resolve this, associate the `transition` to the element id.
2. The `removeClass` and `addClass` are probably getting applied to the same frame that appends `#search_hint` while rendering. To mitigate this you could wait for the frame to render, and then add/remove the class. I've done this using `setTimeout` with timeout value zero.

```js
const searchHint = `
  <h3 id="search_hint" class="invizible">
    Enter a search term to continue!
  </h3>
`;
$('#search_label').append(searchHint);

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#search_hint').removeClass('invizible').addClass('make_vizible');
},0);
```

```css
#search_hint {
  color: white;
  transition: color 1s ease;
}


#search_hint.invizible {
  color: white;
}

#search_hint.make_vizible {
  color: #404040;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search_label">

</div>
```